Calculating M-values in specific coordinate system ArcGIS Pro
I have an issue with calculating M-values in ArcGIS Pro: I need to calculate them in a specific coordinate system.
For example, the M-coordinate of a first vertex is set to 0; next should be 0 + the length between them (calculated in a chosen UTM zone), and so on.
It was easy to do in ArcMap by setting the coordinate system of a project:

and right-clicking a line and setting value of M for first vertex:

The result was M-values calculated in chosen CS:

With this method the last M coordinate is the same as the line length in chosen CS.
In ArcGIS Pro it doesn't work like that. It sets M-values in CS of the dataset.
How can I overcome this? Maybe ArcPy can be used?

Edit and add more detail to your question, what do you mean by in a specific coordinate system? What is the coordinate system it is in and what do you want it in?

Measures (M values) are not in any coordinate system. The values are completely user-controlled (within the false-M/M-scale storage mechanism).

@Hornbydd added more details, did it become more clear?

@Vince Do AcrMap and AcrGIS use different storage mechanism? I don't get it

I wrote a python toolbox to overcome this issue. If somebody needs it, contact me.

Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.

I was able to replicate the issue. From my limited testing it appears that distance as M is captured in the native coordinate system of the dataset and not what the map is displaying as. This is what I would expect it to be. But as @Vince points out M could be in any units its not tied to the coordinate system, but in most cases it would be distance.
May be in ArcMap your dataset was already in UTM?
Best practise in setting up your editing environment is discussed on this page, take particular note about coordinate systems.
Then confirm your units are appropriate, do this under options > units. Below for me they are set to Meter.


In ArcMap, M is captured in the Data Frame's coordinate system (I use ArcMap 10.7 for this).
I already tried this with different coordinate systems for datasets. It didn't help. And I used the same classes in same databases in these two programs.
Checked units, they are set to meter as well.

Then I suggest you raise it as an idea and explain your use case scenario to ESRI, they may put that behaviour back in some future release, suggest a work around or ignore it?

Update: you were right about M coordinates being calculated in dataset's CS in ArcGis Pro. But my data contains features from multiple UTM zones and I can't project every line. Added this in the original question.
